# How to add a theme to marketplace visualstudio code?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-code, marketplace

Actually wrote the theme, how can I add it to marketplace? 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/

All upload to GIT - https://github.com/CB9TOIIIA/Theme-RealBlackBoard
VSIX - made

Comment: THX :) but also redirect to setting profile alwayse... redirect to profile.

Comment: Right link: https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/docs/integrate/extensions/publish/overview

Answer (score 0):

Right link to publish your VCS app marketplace:

https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/docs/integrate/extensions/publish/overview